# Selenium Discord channel select last message

Tags: python, html, selenium

I am trying select last message on discord channel with selenium
I can't find xpath. xpath is changing every time for last message. I just want copy last message on the channel. Last message id changing. Please help me. This code is logging and goes rotate to chanel.

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

import os, shutil

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://discord.com/login")

time.sleep(6)

#--------------- Edit Here -------------------------------------------------------------

# Enter your account details here 

username = ''

password = ''

# Copy the URL of channel where you wanna send messages and paste below

channelURL = "https://discord.com/channels/775349757060186142/77535656021144289331"

#-------------- Edit End ----------------------------------------------------------------

# Initialize and input email

username_input = driver.find_element_by_name('email')

username_input.send_keys(username)

# Initialize and input password

password_input = driver.find_element_by_name('password')

password_input.send_keys(password)

# Initialize and login

login_button = 

login_button.click()

print(">>Login Complete!")

time.sleep(10)

driver.get(channelURL)

print(">Opening The Server Link...")

time.sleep(5)

# Msg Sending

msgoutput = # I can't find last message's xpath

print("last message is")

print(msgoutput)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this xpath to find your element by xpath:

```
//ol[@data-list-id="chat-messages"]/li[last()]//div[contains(@class,'messageContent')]
```

**Explaining the xpath**

1. `//ol[@data-list-id="chat-messages"]` --> An `ol` element with id `chat-messages` (Which is the list of messages)
2. `/li[last()]` --> We get the last `li` element from the previous list (Which is the last message)
3. `//div[contains(@class,'messageContent')]` --> Inside the previous `li` we have a div which class contains `messageContent` which is the element that contains the text.

So, take the text from that element and you should get the latest message.